# Lazy tree traversal iterator in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, lazy-evaluation, tree-traversal

If my tree is defined as such:

```
case class Node(value: Int, children: Seq[Node])
```

but for the sake of the argument, let's say that accessing the children are expensive such that I want to traverse them only when I actuall need to.

If a non-strict, eager DFS traversal on `Node` is defined as

```
def traverse(node: Node): Unit = {
  node.children foreach { child => traverse(child) }
}
```

How do I create a lazy counterpart of it?

Ideally I will have an `iterator` method which returns an iterator based on DFS traversal ordering that only evaluates the next element when `next()` is called on it:

```
val tree = Node(1, Seq(Node(2, Nil), Node(3, Nil)))
val dfsIt = tree.iterator // get a iterator with a DFS traversal ordering
val nextNode = dfsIt.next() // compute which element to return on demand
```

Comment: I think your sample code is wrong, should be `node.children foreach { child => traverse(child) }` . Notice the `traverse(child)` instead of `traverse(node)`

Comment: you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Node(value: Int, children: Seq[Node]) {

  def dfsIterator: Iterator[Node] = {
    println(value)
    children.iterator.map(_.dfsIterator).flatten ++ Iterator(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very elegant. The only improvement would be to replace `map...flatten` with `flatMap`. (Was it not available in 2015?)